# Can Mathematica evaluate a continued fraction using Gauss's $K$ operator?

Tags: continued-fractions

I don't know a whole lot about Mathematica, and this is a fairly uncommon notation, so here goes:

How do I tell Mathematica to evaluate this? $$1+\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{K}}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{i+1}$$

where $$\underset{i=1}{\overset{\infty}{K}}\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\cfrac{a_{1}}{b_{1}+\cfrac{a_{2}}{b_{2}+\cfrac{a_{3}}{b_{3}+\cfrac{a_{4}}{b_{4}+\ddots{}}}}}$$

Must I convert to a different notation first? Or can I create a custom notation like this? Thanks for your time.

**Update**: I didn't know the `ContinuedFractionK` command, but unfortunately:

```
In[1] = ContinuedFractionK[(-1)^(i-1),i+1,{i,1,Infinity}]
```

produces only the formula in its proper format. How can I get a numerical value?

P.S. I am working in Wolfram Cloud Open Access in my browser, if that matters.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation, but is [`ContinuedFractionK`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuedFractionK.html) relevant to your problem?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, that is what I am looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MarcoB Hold on though, when I use this function, it doesn't actually evaluate it. It just formats in the proper way. How can I evaluate it?

Comment: It will evaluate to a value IF it knows / can calculate the value of the infinite sum. If not, it returns unevaluated. Mathematica is not magic :-) For instance,`1+ ContinuedFractionK[1, {n, 1, Infinity}]` evaluates to `GoldenRatio`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ContinuedFractionK[a[i], b[i], {i, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

```
cf = 1 + ContinuedFractionK[(-1)^(i - 1), i + 1, {i, 1, Infinity}]
```

[image]

With 25 terms this converges to 50 decimal places

```
(seq = Table[
    1 + ContinuedFractionK[(-1)^(i - 1), i + 1, {i, 1, m}],
    {m, 20, 25}]) // N[#, 50] &

(* {1.5904911352531017312102344422665947246625994232424, \
1.5904911352531017312102344422665947246626211968387, \
1.5904911352531017312102344422665947246626212398613, \
1.5904911352531017312102344422665947246626212397833, \
1.5904911352531017312102344422665947246626212397832, \
1.5904911352531017312102344422665947246626212397832} *)

cfn = seq // Last

(* 574085431771810544409993183/360948526557146668699034326 *)
```